# How to add a button in existing application of domino designer?

Tags: lotus-notes, domino-designer-eclipse

I am adding a action button in a folder(inbox) of existing application (incoming internet mail) but when i launch notes client it does not showing that action button.

Comment: That's a pretty darned broad question.  Does the database use a template?  If so, did you change the template?  Is the folder in a frameset?  Is the button visible to you (i.e., is the access control for the button set to allow you to see it?)  Did you make a button for it, or is it just an action?  These are but a few of the things it could be.

Comment: Check the hide when formula for the button to make sure it is not being hidden.  Also make sure that the design changes have not been overwritten by the mail template.